# Effects of creating a skill systems for litrpg type of world?

Tags: government

I have been reading several books with people having access to status screens and I recently developed an interest in creating such a world myself. What I wanted to ask is:

What would the effects be on a medieval fantasy society if pretty much every skill could be acquired by spending effort and what effect would it have on people if certain people could see their status revealing their skills?

To be more specific: would governments keep their feudalistic nature or would it become a meritocracy since nobody is inherently superior to others?

Comment: Currently your system sounds a lot like reality. I can learn *something* about *pretty much everything*. Granted, I'll probably never be a master musician, but learning the basics should be possible for pretty much everyone with enough time and dedication in our reality. Time and resources to learn are most important. The biggest difference seems to be that you can *see* your stats. You also seem to have two questions. One is about the whole society, which in general is too broad even if I think nothing much would change, the other one is about the governments, which looks opinion-based.

Comment: In addition to @Secespitus remarks: It will change a lot of thing if you never forget a skill. In games, you can be a master in 20 jobs because you don't have to use them often in order to keep them. in real life, if you don't use a skill for a certain time you'll forget it. Do you remember all topics you've seen in school?

Comment: Medieval *governments* (such as they were) were not "feudal" in any reasonable understanding of the words "government" and "feudal". it was the *society* which had a feudal structure -- or, in Marxist terms, the *mode of production* was feudal. In fact, one of the most salient characteristic of the western European medieval world is that there was very little in the way of government -- the society was made up of a multitude of small practically autonomous units. One of the few areas where low-born people could progress was in government service.

Comment: Can anybody else see my "status screen" or only me?  If only me, I don't believe there would be any difference at all.  If others can see it, it would change the way educational systems worked (testing would become less meaningful and awarding educational degrees would become more accurate) and there would be no fake professionals (call yourself a doctor? Show me your stats!).  People could prove their competence, which would affect how we judge people suitable for public office, etc.  But if stat screens are private, there would be no change at all.

Comment: Most people wouldn't be able to read it. Those in the government included.

Comment: @Secespitus I'd propose that people's evaluation of themselves and others in all respects is based on animal impulses that are painted with a thin layer of reason and submerged beneath a whole ton of evolved social means of coping with that lack of factual data. With access to an apparently objective measure, people would 'finally' be given a tool to accurately evaluate comparative 'value.' In other words, nothing at all like reality.